# In topology, why continuous function defined in terms of its inverse?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If $(X,T_x),(Y,T_y)$ are topologies then $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous iff $u\in T_y\rightarrow f^{-1}(u)\in T_x$.

My question why not define $f$ as continuous iff $u\in T_x\rightarrow f(u)\in T_y$

are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: The inverse image definition lines up with the correct $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity, so it is the correct generalization.  The forward image version makes most constant maps DIScontinuous, so that cannot be the right definition.

Comment: The other definition is also useful. Such maps are called **open**.

Comment: Are you aware that $f^{-1}$ in the definition refers to the preimage of $f$ and not its inverse? The latter may not exist.